# How you call the constant $\alpha$ within the heat equation in general and in terms of electromagnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, soft-question, waves, notation, physical-constants

The [heat equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) or diffusion equation does contain a constant $\alpha$.

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \alpha \nabla^2 u=0$$

**How is it called?**

I'm interested in a general name which can be used for different circumstances apart from heat transfer and diffusion of fluids. For example in electromagnetism this constant is related to the [skindepth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skindepth) $\delta$ via:

$$\alpha = \frac{\sqrt{2j}}{\delta} = \sqrt{j\omega \kappa \mu}$$

If there is no name, what would you suggest?

Comment: For an electromagnetic wave, this is the *propagation constan*.

Comment: @Tinchito thanks! that was already was I was looking for!

Comment: sure? then I post it as an answer... :)

Comment: @Tinchito: Well I think it is alright, what I'm doing has nothing really to do with waves, rather effective reluctances in different materials, thats why I never stumbled of this name the whole time.  But I think it is appropriate for this case also.

Comment: I understand. When you find the solution of the Helmholtz equation for the electric field (wave equation), the meaning of this constant is evident, and hence its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an electromagnetic wave, this is the *propagation constant*. It can be expressed as the sum of two terms: the *attenuation constant* and the *phase constant*.